# Which wallets work with payment codes?

Tags: reusable-payment-code, samourai-wallet

I know the samurai wallet for android has support for payment codes, what other wallets support payment codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for the Payment code situation

[BIP 47](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0047.mediawiki) (extension of BIP 32) and [BIP 75](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0075.mediawiki) (extention of BIP 70)

Wallets that implement BIP 47

- [Samurai](https://samouraiwallet.com/features.html)
- [Stash](http://stashcrypto.com/products.html)
- [Billion](https://github.com/Billionapp/billion-wallet-ios)

Wallets that implement BIP 75

- [BreadWallet](https://github.com/voisine/breadwallet-ios/issues/289)
- [Netki](https://medium.com/@justinwnewton/https-medium-com-justinwnewton-bip-75-improving-blockchain-usability-and-privacy-543305a659ed)

Wallets that implement BIP 70 and may implement BIP 75

- [Coinbase](https://www.coindesk.com/coinbase-adds-bitcoin-payment-protocol-safer-transactions/)
- [BitPay & Copay](https://blog.bitpay.com/bitpay-and-payment-protocol/)
- [Mycelium](https://mycelium.com/)

Sources: [Coinjournal](https://coinjournal.net/bip-47-vs-bip-75-will-bitcoin-wallets-maintain-privacy-becoming-easier-use/), [/r/Bitcoin](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3alzga/bip47_reusable_payment_codes/), [BitcoinMagazine](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/bip-simplifies-bitcoin-wallets-for-the-everyday-user-1461856604/)

Answer (score 1):

Samourai Wallet on Android and Billion app on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

there's no wallet support payment-code.

since payment-code system made by Samurai wallet and this feature just for samurai wallet and it's not possible to use payment-code outside Samurai wallet.

Comment: This is incorrect. Payment codes are standardized by BIP 47.

Comment: So, the real question is, which wallets have implemented support for BIP 47?